# How can I send keystrokes to a program thats inactive in Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, networking, subprocess, sendkeys

I want to create a program that will allow me to 'multi-box' a flash game (ROTMG). All I've seen for sending keystrokes in Mac is the applescript but that only works for programs that are active, My multibox programs will be minimized. :/

In windows I know this can be done using the `win32` module but of course this does not work on mac.

Any ideas? Is it possible to perhaps run the actual game in python and send `player movements` on the network packet level. Or perhaps even clone packets from the main window?